# Can magnetisation component along a specific direction be measured by a magnetometer?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

In a magnetometer, like VSM, we measure the magnetisation of the sample which is the net magnetisation. Is it possible to measure the component of the magnetisation along a specific direction? If yes, what instrument can do this?